# How to calculate ratios between shapefiles?

Tags: python, spatial

So I have two shapefiles, one is a grid and one is a map of the world's land. I am trying to find the ratio of land in each cell of the 'grid' shapefile but I am stuck.

[Here are the shapefiles](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zR37cB07NWovuHeATInWjS0hRRVcZgdI?usp=sharing)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import point, Polygon, mapping, shape

grid =gpd.read_file('grid.shp')
World_Land = gpd.read_file("World_Land.shp")

for index1, row1 in World_Land.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in grid.iterrows():
        if row1['geometry'].intersection(row2['geometry']):
            grid.loc[index2,'ratio'] = (row1['geometry'].area / row2['geometry'].area)

grid.plot(column = 'ratio')
```

This gives me something but I want to make sure I am making a choropleth map correctly and calculating the ratios correctly.

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, you may want to ask over on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm close, I'm going to update the question and cross post.